# can't attain desired format with php's utf-8_encode or decode on string containing "\x"

Tags: php

I have a bunch of string data containing format like **"\xaa", "\xam", "\xaz"**. when I print them to screen or tried to match them character by character it wouldn't work for instance there is so much going on with these strings that I don't understand:

```
echo "\xaa"; // prints a question mark to the screen
echo "\xa"; // simply shows noting 
$strZero = strlen("\xaa"); // shows 1 as length of string
$strOne = strlen("\xaz"); // but this shows 2 as length of string
```

I don't know what's going on I mean I know it got something to do with utf8 encoding or something. What I want is to escape these strings like "\\xaa" and get the characters and the length should be 4.

I know there are  similar questions which suggest things like:

```
$str = "\xaa"
utf8_encode($str); // this gives a not "\\xaa"
// or
utf8_decode($str); // this returns a question mark "?"
```

None of these returned the escape strings the way I want how would I go about dealing with this pragmatically instead of escaping each string manually by placing an extra backslash before then.

Comment: \ has a special use in PHP. It denotes an [escape sequence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: The question is very unclear. If you don't want \x to have a special meaning, you can use single quotes, `$str = '\xaa'` I don't see why you think it has something to do with utf8. Sure utf8 uses the byte 0xaa, but so does every binary file format

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mis-understanding of [escape sequences](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). `\` is used to denote an escape char. `\x` has a special meaning

> \xhh
>      character with hex code `hh`

In [UTF-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl):

> U+00EA ê   c3 aa   LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
>   U+000A     0a

Which would explain you're getting a ? (if your browser doesn't understand UTF-8 `0xaa`) and nothing (since `0xa` seems to be not printable).

If you actually want `\xaa` or `\xa` as the value of the string, you will need the `\\` escape char:

```
    echo "\\xaa"; // Should show \xaa
    echo "\\xa"; // Should show \xa 
    $strZero = strlen("\\xaa"); // should be 4 as length of string
    $strOne = strlen("\\xaz"); //  should be 4 as length of string
```

Comment: BTW: Is someone wants to edit, I'd appreciate it. Can't get the second box to format right. Or the first. It keeps saying there's "un-parsed code".